# Data Source is Available only after deployment failure in openshift

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource, openshift

I have an application at Openshift. I am using scaling app option. When i try to deploy, it tells that Datasource is not found. But after the deployment fails, datasource displays in new corrected service logs. Please help me. Here is the last part of logs. Thanks!!

2014/04/07 07:04:44,586 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ROOT.war"

2014/04/07 07:04:51,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for javamanor

2014/04/07 07:04:52,092 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.ROOT.war" is using a private module 
("org.w3c.css.sac:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.

2014/04/07 07:04:52,094 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.ROOT.war" is using a private module ("net.sourceforge.cssparser:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.

2014/04/07 07:04:52,669 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment ROOT.war

2014/04/07 07:04:52,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserServiceImpl in deployment unit deployment "ROOT.war" are as follows:

```
java:global/ROOT/UserServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.UserServiceImpl
java:app/ROOT/UserServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.UserServiceImpl
java:module/UserServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.UserServiceImpl
java:global/ROOT/UserServiceImpl
java:app/ROOT/UserServiceImpl
java:module/UserServiceImpl
```

2014/04/07 07:04:52,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named CommonServiceImpl in deployment unit deployment "ROOT.war" are as follows:

```
java:global/ROOT/CommonServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.CommonServiceImpl
java:app/ROOT/CommonServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.CommonServiceImpl
java:module/CommonServiceImpl!com.javamanor.common.service.CommonServiceImpl
java:global/ROOT/CommonServiceImpl
java:app/ROOT/CommonServiceImpl
java:module/CommonServiceImpl
```

2014/04/07 07:04:54,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)

2014/04/07 07:04:54,278 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ROOT.war

2014/04/07 07:04:54,733 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#javamanor\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#javamanor\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS]"]}

2014/04/07 07:04:54,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 164ms

2014/04/07 07:04:54,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS (new available)

2014/04/07 07:04:54,891 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#javamanor\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#javamanor\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS]"]}}}